# in ggplot2 , how to make different legend on the different position

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Blow plot have two legend `size` and `color` ,currently the positon on right .How to marke size legend on the left ,meanwhile the color legend on the top ? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
diamonds %>% head(30) %>% ggplot(aes(x=clarity ,y=price,
                        size=color,
                        color=x))+
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default option to place legends at different positions. But using `cowplot` and `patchwork` you could achieve your desired result like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
library(patchwork)

p <- diamonds |> 
  head(30) |> 
  ggplot(aes(
    x = clarity, y = price,
    size = color,
    color = x
  )) +
  geom_point()

legend_size <- get_legend(
  p + guides(color = "none") + theme(legend.position = "left")
)

p <- p + 
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  guides(size = "none")

wrap_elements(legend_size) + p +
  plot_layout(widths = c(1, 9))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are creating a graph in Arabic or Hebrew, I find it extremely odd to place the legend on the left side because it looks confusing along with a Y-label and and the Y-axis itself.
Having said that, you can easily tweak the location using legend.position() and position it wherever you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
diamonds %>% head(30) %>% ggplot(aes(x=clarity ,y=price,
                                     size=color,
                                     color=x))+
  theme(legend.position = "left") +
  geom_point()
```